# alternative approach to count number of rotation required to find original string from rotated string

Tags: java, algorithm

WE got 2 strings one correct and one its rotation? we have to tell that after how many steps of rotation of 2nd string we get the original (first)string(suppose only one side rotation is allowed)

but problem here is traditional method of rotating one charater of string at a time and then comparing rotated  string with original is taking more time than allowed 
which alternative approach can be used?

string1: `david`
string2: `vidda`

(processing part-rotation first: `avidd`, second: `david`, so answer is 2)
output: `2`

Comment: What is the question? Any code to share that might explain your issue?

Comment: we got 2 strings one correct(danielson) and other its rotated form(sondaniel) 
we have to find after how many rotations second string(sondaniel) will become first
(danielson), suppose only right(anyone side) side rotation is allowed 

trdational approach is rotate one character at a time
then compare it with original 

rot1 lsondanie
rot2 elsondani
rot3 ielsondan

rot6 danielson

output 6 

how can we do it faster as it takes a lot of time

using traditional approach by rotating one character at a time then compare it

Comment: Edit your question instead of explaining your issue in a comment. And don't forget  to show us what you have so far.

Comment: its same i just changed string from david to danielson

Comment: Well you got your homework done without any effort so all is fine then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String one = "david"; 
String two = "vidda";

one.concat(one).indexOf(two)
```

would work wouldn't it?

Comment: Well... I didn't know that Java had implemented such a method by itself... It works but can you explain what these function do?

Comment: concatenate the two strings together: "daviddavid" then find the starting point for the rotated string in the new string (the index) of "vidda" in the concatenated strings

Comment: Well... Nice solution!

Comment: And I take my time to work on an algorithm that does all the same for nothing xD

*At least my approach uses less memory*  :)

Comment: And I guess your algorithm has a worst case runtime of `O(2*n)` mine has `O(n)`

Comment: thanks a lot i was writing too much code loops inside loop and you did it in one line (y)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my approach is fast enough... But it has a runtime of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the strings.

This approach only works if it is given that it is solvable and if both strings have the same length:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "david";
    String string2 = "avidd";
    char[] a = string1.toCharArray();
    char[] b = string2.toCharArray();
    int pointer = a.length-1;
    int off = 0;
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = b.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (b[i] == a[pointer]) {   //found a match
            current++;              //our current match is one higher
            pointer--;              //pointer of string1 goes one back
        } else if (current != 0) {  //no match anymore and we have had a match
            i ++;                   //we have to recalculate the actual position in the next step of the loop
            off += current;         //we have to rotate `current` times more
            current = 0;            //reset current match
            pointer = a.length-1;   //reset pointer
        } else {                    //no match and we didn't have had a match the last time
            off ++;                 //we have to rotate one more time
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Rotate: " + off);
}
```

basically it starts at the end of both the strings and goes back to the beginning until it doesn't get any differences any more. If it does get a difference at any point it adds the current counter to `off` and recontinues at the end of `string1`.

My algorithm does **not** check if the strings are the same after having done `off` rotations.